Isotope trigger by passing parameter
Hi below is my script but its not working
$(window).load(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  var buttonFilter = '.'+hash;          
  $('button#'+hash).addClass('is-checked');    
  var filterValue = $(buttonFilter).data('filter');   
 $grid.isotope(); 
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

I have passed a parameter to URL from another page and from that value I want to trigger isotope directly but not working.

where is $grid defined?

Yes $grid is defined

var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;
var checkFilter;
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.filters_content').isotope({
itemSelector: '.element-item',
layoutMode: 'fitRows',
stagger: 30,
filter: function() {
var $this = $(this);
var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
var checkResult = checkFilter ? $this.is( checkFilter ) : true;
return searchResult && buttonResult && checkResult;
}
});

Instead of adding this as comment, you should have edited your question. Anyways, when you say "not working," do you mean the filter isn't functioning, and all items are displayed without any filtering applied? Please be more specific.
